# Writing large object to disk as json file instead of memory .NET

Tags: c#, json, .net, memory-management, ram

I have a List collection of class objects in c# of approximate size 27000 bytes, and I want to make millions of instances of these objects available to the user of the code. The code I have written to instantiate the objects seems to work well, I am able to fill up to approx 3 million objects with the data I generate before the processor stops running the code efficiently. I run out of memory and then the code runs indefinitely or crashes.
I was hoping to be able to write parts of the request (e.g. 3 mill to memory, 7 mill objects to disk) as a json file. What I fail to understand, is how writing to disk can help memory usage. Don't the objects have to exist in memory in the first place, since I want to set their values? Any tips are appreciated.

Comment: Add your code and exceptions

Comment: I don't know why you need this amount of data loaded to memory, if what you are trying is to "store" this dada and it don't have any relations between them, then you can try storing it in a mongoldb database: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/csharp/

Comment: Relevant code would help immensely.....

Comment: Memory should only be used for working operations, otherwise it should be pushed out  to form of persistence, db, queue, file etc.

If you really need to do this sort of stuff then I would suggest having 1 object  cloning for other operations/users as and when needed. You would also have to manage the life cycle of these object for this to run efficiently.

Depending on what you are doing exactly, look at dictionaries and hashtables, these are really fast to work with.

Hope that points you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

> What I fail to understand, is how writing to disk can help memory
> usage

Your RAM is rather limited. So you typically would only load a reasonable chunk of your data from a volume into RAM for processing. Given your example it is very unlikely that you need 7 million large objects at the same time.

> Don't the objects have to exist in memory in the first place, since I
> want to set their values?

Only the one you are currently processing